# Association with sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am new to node js, I have a problem trying to get records from two related tables: Province and City.

A city has many provinces (this is my relationship)

I use this method to make the query:

```
async function getProvinces ()
   {
     return await municipality.findAll ({
       include: [{
           model: city,
           required: true,
           attributes: [['name', 'city']]
       }],
       attributes: ['provinceId', 'name']
     })
   }
```

and this returns me:

> `[{"provinceId": 1, "name": "province 1", "city": {"city": "city 1"}}]`

My problem is the following:

when trying to access the city object I get an **undefined**

> `data [0] .city.city`

Why this ??

what I need is to return a response with this format:

> `{"provinceId": 1, "name": "province 1", "city": "city 1"}`

**Update (Example)**

```
const getProvincesMethod= async ()=>
{
  const value = await getProvinces()

  if(!value) return null

  var list = []

  value.forEach(item => {
    list.push(getProvinceObject(item))
  });

  return list
}

function getProvinceObject(data)
{
  if(!data) return null
  console.log(data)
  return {
    provinceId: data.provinceId,
    name: data.name,
    city: data.city.city
  }
}

async function getProvinces ()
   {
     return await municipality.findAll ({
       include: [{
           model: city,
           required: true,
           attributes: [['name', 'city']]
       }],
       attributes: ['provinceId', 'name']
     })
   }
```

Comment: show a code where you get and access city.city

Comment: Ready, I added my example

Comment: Remove unneccesary [] in attributes: [['name', 'city']]. It has to be attributes: ['name', 'city']

Answer (score 0):

You can access `city` as follows -

```
data[0].dataValues.city.dataValues.city
```

Hope it helps!